# "docker run -p" assigned the localhost IP but did not effect on Macos

Tags: macos, docker

I use the following command to create a container on MacOS，my docker version is "Docker for Mac",

```sh
docker run -itd --name dns-mysql1  --network=host  -p 192.168.43.178:53:53 brilliance/dns-mysql:latest
```

but when it starts，it does not affect，the mapped port and IP address has changed,

As follows:
[image: ip address becomes 127.0.0.1]

but it does work on Ubuntu or other Linux system. I want to know why.

Comment: I am guessing that Docker for Mac doesn't support the full -p syntax because, like on windows, dockerd runs in a vm.

Comment: `--network=host` and `-p` don't work together: since host networking basically disables all of Docker's networking support, `-p` doesn't have any effect.  You then hit the problem that [host networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) doesn't actually work on MacOS.  Does removing the `--network=host` option help?